# Parsing Android Manifest File to look for the uses-permission tag using python

Tags: android, python, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am parsing the uses-permission tag in an xml file(androidmanifest.xml) mentioned in an android application

I have tried implementing a for loop to make it iterative but i have failed and so am here

Python:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
file = open('/root/Desktop/AndroidManifest.xml','r')
data = file.read()
file.close()
dom = parseString(data)
  xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('uses-permission')[0].toxml()

  print xmlTag
```

Output:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>
```

for loop mistake:

```
for uses-permission in xmlTag:
    #print child.tag, child.attrib
    print xmlTag.tag
xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('uses-permission')[1].toxml()
xmlTag= dom._get_childNodes
#print xmlTag
```

Answer (score 6):

To find all the permission tags, try iterating over the nodes that `dom.getElementsByTagName('uses-permission')` returns instead of accessing only the node at index `0`:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

data = ''
with open('/root/Desktop/AndroidManifest.xml','r') as f:
    data = f.read()
dom = parseString(data)
nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('uses-permission')
# Iterate over all the uses-permission nodes
for node in nodes:
    print node.toxml()
```

or if you want just the permission and not the xml, you can replace `node.toxml()` with `node.getAttribute('android:name')`.